# Perl: Take arguments from both command line and [piped STDIN|file], using Getopt::Long

Tags: perl, stdin, getopt-long

Hi I wanted to implement both command line argument1, and either piped STDIN (through lone single dash '-') or a filename as argument2, using Getop::Long in Perl. In perldoc it is merely mentioned a little bit "A lone dash on the command line will now be a legal option, and using it will set variable $stdio": (https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html). But this is far from what I can use. I tried the following

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
my ($se, $st);
GetOptions("se=s" => \$s, '' => \$st) or die "Usage: $0 -s <tab|space|comma>\n";
$st = <STDIN>;
print "$se\n$st\n";
```

However $st only returns the first line or should I use a filehandle? Then what if the lone single dash '-' is not there and a filename is specified as argument2? Thanks a lot,

Comment: Can you show examples of usage you need? When you set up an option `--o` (for example) with Getopt, both `script.pl -o val file` and `echo "..." | script.pl -o val` will read in the option value and you'll be able to read either from the pipe or the file with `while (<>)`.  (Is that not what you want?)

Comment: @zdim It is something like `script.pl -s tab filename` or `head -3 filename | script.pl -s tab -`

Comment: Then that should work exactly as in my comment (see @ikegami answer). Note that you do not need the `-` for what you want.

Comment: Aha yes thanks a lot @zdim

Answer (score 2):

Just use `<>` (short for `<ARGV>`) instead of `<STDIN>`. `ARGV` is a special handle that reads from STDIN if `@ARGV` is empty, and reads from the each of the files specified in `@ARGV` if it's not.

```
GetOptions("se=s" => \my $se)
   or die "Usage: $0 -s <tab|space|comma>\n";

my $st = <>;
```

Comment: I tried <> instead of <STDIN> and it is the same - only the first row is printed. What I want is something like `script.pl -s tab filename` or `head -3 filename | script.pl -s tab -`

Comment: @YiranGuo  The answer shows you the principle, the main point being to use `<>` (without `STDIN`).  In order to read more use `while (<>) { ... }` instead of reading it into a scalar variable.  (Or, you can read it into an array, which will then fetch all lines, but I'd recommend to use a `while` instead.)